# jQuery or CSS to create image tiles/grids (for 1/3, 2/3) patterns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have images in a loop that I want to display, and I want to create this pattern:

[image]

How would I do something like this? I was thinking of using background-image in my view to dynamically display the images.

I even looked at a bunch of jQuery plugins, but nothing can fit my needs.

This is what I have so far:

```
.home-img-grp
  - @projects.order('created_at desc').first(6).each do |project|
    - project.project_images.first(1).each do |image|
      .grid{style: "background-image:url(#{image.photo.url})"}
```

Comment: bootstrap grid, http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: @depperm thought about it that way and tried it, but this is for dynamic purposes and its alternating... If you can show me how it would be done, that'll be great.

Comment: [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html) are two javascript libs for creating dynamic grids / layouts.

Comment: @max I think they require you to have a size. I'd like it to automatically create a simple one that'll automatically give you 1/3 or 2/3 of the container, similar to how bootstrap works.

Comment: Both masonry and isotype can take a set of odd shaped objects and stack them optimally. Check the demos